# How to set "Unavailable" word for null values in DataGridView

Tags: c#, sql-server, winforms, datagridview

I have an `employees` table in which first number is set as **not null** and second number that can be **null* so when I call the `employees` information to view their information in `DataGridView` the null values appear as empty cells but I want to show "Unavailable" word instead of the empty cell , so how can I do this?

Comment: In C# use int? which allows integers to be null.

Comment: IMHO this needs to be closed - question is too broad.

Comment: But varchar is a string not a NUMBER!!!

Answer (score 3):

You can use either of these options:

1. Set [`NullValue`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridviewcellstyle.nullvalue(v=vs.110).aspx) property of `DefaultCellStyle` of the column. It sets the cell display value corresponding to a cell value of `DBNull.Value` or `null`.
2. Use `CellFormatting` event and set `e.Value` when the value of cell is `DBNull.Value` or `null`

**Example 1**

```
this.dataGridView1.Columns[1].DefaultCellStyle.NullValue = "Unavailable";
```

**Example 2**

```
void dataGridView1_CellFormatting(object sender, DataGridViewCellFormattingEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.ColumnIndex < 0 || e.RowIndex < 0)
        return;

    if (e.Value == DBNull.Value || e.Vallue == null)
        e.Value = "Unavailable";
}
```

Comment: I tried both options but there is no change the same empty cell appear no "Unavailable" word appear

Comment: If none of these options worked for you, it means the value of cell is not null, probably it contains some spaces instead of null.

Comment: Always to test the solutions, use a clean environment, Here is the code which I use for test: `var dt = new DataTable();
dt.Columns.Add("A");
dt.Columns.Add("B");
dt.Rows.Add("1", DBNull.Value);
dt.Rows.Add("2", DBNull.Value);
this.dataGridView1.DataSource = dt;`

Comment: That's a good example to check the values in a testing environment @Reza Aghaei.

Comment: @RezaAghaei these are my codes for insert process ` cn.Open();
 cmd = new SqlCommand("insert into emp(empName,empAdd,empBdate,empPhone1,empPhone2,empSSN,empEmail,empQualf,empPass,empPerm) values ('" + empRegNametxt.Text + "','" + empRegAddtxt.Text + "', '" + empRegBdatePicker.Text + "', '" + empRegPhone1txt.Text + "', '" + empRegPhone2txt.Text + "'," + empRegSSNtxt.Text + " ,'" + empRegEmailtxt.Text + "','" + empRegQualftxt.Text + "','" + empRegPasstxt.Text + "','" + getPerm + "')", cn);
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();`

Comment: and I am sure that my textBoxes does not contain any spaces look in my codes the "empPhone2 and empEm‌​ail" are left empty for more than one employee when registering but when I used these suggested codes nothing made any change and gave me my aim

Comment: That's why I shared a simple code to test the solution. You mix many things to test, an Insert query, database field types, textboxes and so on. This is not a good test. An effective test is what I shared. I know you have an issue in your application and you like to find the problem and solve issue. Buy you should verify answers using simple codes which focus on a certain problem.

Comment: Another **guess** could be the field of database may be `nchar` or `char` with fixed width and contain spaces in database.

Comment: Just verify the answer by using the simple test which I shared. Then if my **guess** about your insert query didn't help, ask a new question about your insert query.

Comment: Also JFYI, the benefit of the solution which I shared using both options, is even if you set a field to Null at run-time by pressing Ctrl+0 then when you move focus to next field the "Unavailable" value will be shown in that field.

Answer (score 2):

Change your `Select` statement to something like this (use `CASE WHEN`):

```
SELECT Id, CASE WHEN SecondNumber IS NULL THEN 'Unavailable' ELSE SecondNumber END AS SecondNumber
FROM yourTable
```

Comment: the same empty cell appear no "Unavailable" word appear

Comment: @Tima'aTamim So I'm pretty sure the value of the cell is not null. Because based on this query it should replace the `NULL` cells with `Unavailable`. Probably it contains space instead of NULL!

Answer (score 1):

This solution would also include an extension method so please make the following extension method.

this is what we will need to set the values of the grid in a more clean way (optional though)

```
 public static void ApplyAction<T>(this IEnumerable<T> source, Action<T> action)
 {
     foreach (var entity in source)
     {
         action(entity);

     }
 }
```

now all you have to do is going to be the following :

```
dataGridView1.Rows.OfType<DataGridViewRow>().Where(c => c.Cells[ColumnName.Index].Value == null).ApplyAction(new Action<DataGridViewRow>(c => c.Cells[ColumnName.Index].Value = "Unavailable"));
```